# Firebase Android failed to convert HashMap to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting an error while retriving data from Firebase in Android app.

**Error**

[image: here.]

**My code:**

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = databaseReference.child(path);

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
```

"path" - child's name.

**And my**
[image: Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code read all data from the root of your data.

So what you get in the `dataSnapshot` passed to `onDataChange` is:

```
{
  "uzmtn": "data"
}
```

Then you call `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)` on it, which isn't possible: the value in the snapshot isn't a string.

There are two simple options to fix it:

1. read data lower in the tree
2. get the correct child from the existing snapshot

I'll start with the second, since it stays closest to your code.

#### get the correct child from the existing snapshot

Since you're already getting the entire JSON in `dataSnapshot`, you can use the methods of the [DataSnapshot class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) to find the value you want.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference ref = databaseReference.child(path);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.child("uzmtn").getValue(String.class);

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
```

While this works, you're reading slightly more data than is needed. It isn't too bad here, but as a general case: it is best to only read the precise data you need.

To do that, we can...

#### read data lower in the tree

Instead of listening for the root of the database, you can attach a listener straight to the `uzmtn` node:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uzmtn");

DatabaseReference ref = databaseReference.child(path);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
```

If you do that, the `dataSnapshot` will contain precisely the string you are looking for:

```
"data"
```

And with this in the snapshot, the call to `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a hashmap type because you didn't specify what child you want to return . Imagine your data structure like a tree in firebase database , each node has its own value . 
What you want to return it's the child node from a tree , but instead , you return the node itself , which will return the node itself and the whole child node .

Simple solution is

```
dataSnapshot.child('emtz').getValue() .....
```